# Passing custom environment variable from parent to child shell via a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

On the parent shell(root) executing the following:

```sh
SESSION_RECORD=started
```

Output:

```sh
echo $SESSION_RECORD
started
```

However, when I check the status from a shell script, the value is not getting assigned. I am aware it creates a child and executes the script, which is why it doesn't take the variable.

Is there a way I can import that from the parent shell to the child shell?
I don't want to use export as the root variable is dynamic..

Script for reference:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

session=`echo $SESSION_RECORD`
echo $session
if [ "$session" == "started" ]
then
echo "screen records"
else
echo "screen not started"
fi
```

Comment: *'export SESSION_RECORD'* or *'SESSION_RECORD=started ./script'* or positional parameter *'./script started'* (inside script *'session=$1'*)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606033